# Cassandra memory consumption

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra

I have installed cassandra in ubuntu system. cassandra version is 3.11.3 
I wanted to check how much total amount of memory cassandra database is using. Other than top command kindly suggest some command or any other way using which i can come to know what total amount of memory is used by just the cassandra database in ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes Cassandra provides a command line interface for management. You can use nodetool -u username -pw ********** info (if jmx is enabled ) command to get information about how much Heap and Off Heap Memory is used.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsInfo.html#toolsInfo__description

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra provides a command line interface for management. You can use `nodetool info` command to get information about how much Heap and Off Heap Memory is used.

It's also worth mentioning that Cassandra also takes heavy usage of page cache. Note that page cache isn't really occupied memory, you can read more about page cache with a simple web search. Execute the following command to see the current page cache on your machine (-m for megabytes): `free -m`

Comment: i tried executing nodetool info but it's giving null pointer exception error.